# Executing JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests in a same build

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4, junit5

In Maven projects, I have some existing tests relying on JUnit 4. I cannot migrate these tests to JUnit 5 for multiple reasons.
Essentially, some tests depend on a library which uses JUnit 4 runner and code migration may take time.

I would like all the same create new test classes with JUnit 5 that is now released and provides new interesting features.
How to do that ?

Comment: I note that several popular BDD tools do not yet run under JUnit 5.

Comment: @Raedwald When I wrote this post, one of my issues was for Cucumber. For BDD tools that are on several languages, I notice that the standard Java is not always very well updated/supported.

Answer (score 85):

JUnit 5 provides [a way out of the box](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview).

> JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage

Each one is a distinct project and using all of them allows to compile and execute JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests in a same project.

> **JUnit Jupiter** is the combination of the new programming model and extension model for writing tests and extensions in JUnit 5.
>
> **JUnit Vintage** provides a TestEngine for running JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 based tests on the platform.
>
> **The JUnit Platform** serves as a foundation for launching testing frameworks on the JVM

---

**Update : from Maven Surefire `2.22.0`**

From [the JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) :

> Starting with version `2.22.0`, Maven Surefire provides native support
>   for executing tests on the JUnit Platform.

So the configuration is much simpler.
Note that the `junit-4` api dependency is optional as the `engine` dependencies that are now required already pull a default `api` version (it is the case for both junit 4 and 5).

Here is a sample `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>david</groupId>
    <artifactId>jupiter-4-and-5-same-build</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <!-- optional : if we want to use a junit4 specific version -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit5 engine and JUnit 5 API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit4 engine and JUnit 4 API  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional : override the JUnit 4 API version provided by junit-vintage-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

On my GitHub space I added a working sample maven project that you can browse/clone.
URL: https://github.com/ebundy/junit4-and-5-minimal-maven-project

---

**Old way : for Maven Surefire below `2.22.0`**

Here is the minimal configuration to use with Maven to configure the project to compile and run both JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-conf-junit4-5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- JUnit 5 depends on JDK 1.8 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!--  JUnit dependency versions -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <junit-vintage-engine>4.12.1</junit-vintage-engine>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.0.1</junit-jupiter.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.0.1</junit-platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter API to write and compile tests with JUnit5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit 4 to make legacy JUnit 4 tests compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version> <!-- matters until now-->
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- to let surefire to run JUnit 4 but also JUnit 5 tests -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- JUnit vintage engine to run JUnit 3 or JUnit 4 tests -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-vintage-engine}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- JUnit 5 engine to run JUnit 5 tests -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now `mvn test` compiles and runs both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests.

Note 1 : the `junit-vintage-engine` (`4.12.1`) and the `junit` (`4.12`) dependencies don't  specify the same exact version.
This is not an issue at all as :

- their release are not related between them
- `junit-vintage-engine` is designed to run any JUnit **3** or **4** tests.

Note 2 : maven-surefire-plugin with the `2.19.1` version matters whatever you want to compile JUnit 5 test classes or both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 test classes.
Next version of the plugin causes indeed some exceptions during JUnit 5 tests execution but the `2.22.0` that at last solves the issue (see the first part of the answer : "*Update : from Maven Surefire 2.22.0*").

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc ! I tested with a Spring Boot project that surely added it for me. I updated.

Comment: Something I noticed is that if you only have JUnit 4 tests, the Surfire plugin will not recognize any of them.  No matter how many JUnit 4 tests are present, your project needs at least one JUnit Jupiter test to run any tests.

Comment: `junit-vintage-engine` should also be in `test` scope.

Comment: Does this also work with the failsafe plugin? mvn -Dit.test=XXXIT verify does not seem to find the integration test which is JUnit 5?

Answer (score 1):

JUnit have a number of example projects at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples

I had a Gradle project and following https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/main/junit5-migration-gradle worked for me.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/main/junit5-migration-maven is the Maven equivalent - I have not tried it but I imagine that it works too.

Answer (score 0):

For gradle implementation. Just use junit 4 and junit vintage dependencies.

```
dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'
}
```

and also add test to use junitPlatform

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and then both junit4 and junit5 tests should works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question title is general, here is the solution for Gradle using Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform() // Enables JUnit Platform (JUnit 5 + JUnit 4)
}

dependencies {
    // Aggregator dependency that also brings JUnit 5 parameterized tests etc.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.0")
    // The Vintage engine is needed to be able to run JUnit 4 tests
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.10.0")
}
```

```java
public class MyTestClass {
    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test // <- JUnit 5 test
    public void jUnit5test() { /* ... */ }

    @org.junit.Test // <- JUnit 4 test
    public void jUnit4Test() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Execute the tests by running the Gradle `test` or `check` task.