# How to run CamelTest units on maven Build?

Tags: java, maven, junit, apache-camel, maven-surefire-plugin

I created 2 Test classes (1 with 30 testcases, the other one with 10 testcases) in Apache Camel with Spring and Maven.
One of the Test class works fine, and runs if I build with Maven.

`mvn test` <- Works with one Test class

`mvn package` <- Works also with one Test class

But the other test class don't run. Both are in `src/test/java`
Also both test classes are in `target/test-classes/...`
One different is in `target/test-classes/...` the not working class have an second file with `...Test$1.class` in the same folder. But I cannot open it.

And one second different have the classes: The not working class extends from CamelTestSupport and is a junit4. The working test-class is from junit5.

I think the maven-surefire-plugin don't find the junit4 test class. But how can I make maven-surefire-plugin finding junit4 test classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JUnit 4 tests have to be executed with the Vintage engine of JUnit and the JUnit 5 tests with the Jupiter engine.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47158584/8035582) how to configure the POM to use both engines depending on the version of the surefire plugin.

Comment: Ok, now i get the error Message Dez 17, 2020 12:33:46 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNUNG: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Failed to parse version of junit:junit: 4.13.1

Comment: Ok, I change the junit Version to 4.13 now it works. Thank you